# Python Tkinter Def change Var

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I am still learning Tkinter and I am trying to make a simple programe that on a button click will gen three random nums but the def will not change the var, it will print it to the console but will not change the vars

```
from tkinter import *
import random

firstNum = 0
secondNum = 0
thirdNum = 0

def PickNewNums():
    firstNum = random.randint(1, 100)
    secondNum = random.randint(1, 100)
    thirdNum = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(firstNum)
    return firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum

root = Tk()


mainTitle = Label (root, text = "Amazing Title")
newNumbers = Button(root, text = "Get New Numbers", command=PickNewNums)

firstNumber = Label(root, text = firstNum)
secondNumber = Label(root, text = secondNum)
thirdNumber = Label(root, text = thirdNum)

mainTitle.pack()
firstNumber.pack()
secondNumber.pack()
thirdNumber.pack()
newNumbers.pack(side = BOTTOM)
root.geometry("600x300")
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help here guys!

Comment: Briefly: you are creating new local variables rather than modifying the global variables. You are also `return`ing them to nowhere. Use `firstNumber.config(text=firstNum)` instead of `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer wrapping things in a class.

You can associate a Tkinter variable with a label. When the contents of the variable changes, the label is automatically updated:

```
v = StringVar()
Label(root, textvariable=v).pack()
```

To update do :

```
v.set("Hest!")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try